# Как войти в backend yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2

Установил продвинутую версию фреймворка yii2 и теперь стал вопрос: как войти в backend часть, пароль и логин admin admin не работают

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию в Yii2 после установки и попытки войти в backend приложение необходимо подтвердить email. Вы не сможете авторизоваться без этого. Проверьте в Вашей базе данных статус у Вашего пользователя. До подтверждения он будет равняться 9, но как только Вы поменяете статус в Вашей БД на 10, Вы сможете авторизоваться.

Обратите внимание на механику работы авторизации. Файл common/models/User.php, у каждого пользователя есть статус в системе.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 9;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
```